# How do I use raw javascript in jquery and add unique functions to jquery selectors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to do what the title says. As I am new to client side programming with java script all to together I do not know the "right" and "proper" way of achieveing what I need done.

I wish to use a simple javascript function

```
var x;
var items = {};

for (x = 0, x < 7; x++) {
    items[x] = new num;
}

$("li").addclass("items" + num);
```

Is this right? 
Am I on the right track even?

Comment: I would suggest getting a good book on JavaScript and jQuery. I recommend "jQuery in Action" and here's a link to the top JavaScript books on Amazon.com: http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/books/3617/ref=pd_zg_hrsr_b_1_5_last

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what is `num` in your code but I suspect you want to get something like this:

```
$('li').each(function (i) {
    $(this).addClass('items' + i);
});
```

This will add a class with incrementing index to every `li` element. If you run `$("li").addClass("items" + num)` this will add the same class to all `li` elements.

BTW. JavaScript is case sensitive so you must write `addClass` instead of `addclass`.

Comment: You can also use the index argument with $().each() to eliminate the counter. (http://docs.jquery.com/Core/each)

Comment: Oh I just noticed your method... That's the JQuery way (= 
that also solved my problem... thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

More tampering....

and I found that if i did

```
for(var x = 0; x < 7; x++){
    $(".nav li").addClass("items_" + x);
}
```

I'm still not sure why the above didn't work...

oh well...

Comment: This will add the class to all `.nav li` elements on each iteration. To set something different on every item, you need to lopp using `$.each`

Answer (score 0):

RaYell is correct. You need to use `$.each` or you could use `.eq(i)`.. i.e.

```
for(var x = 0; x < $(".nav li).length(); x++){
    $(".nav li").eq(x).addClass("items_" + x);
}
```